# Are const arguments mandatory when overloading the == operator?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

In the first code extract, all arguments are `const` and the code compiles successfully. In the second code extract, the arguments are non-`const` and the code fails spectacularly, sending back the message:

> could be 'bool operator ==(Date &,Date &)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]

Is this because the `==` operator must take `const` arguments?

First

```
int serialDate() const
{
    return m_date.serialNumber(); 
}

friend bool operator == (const Date& a, const Date& b)
{
    return (a.serialDate() == b.serialDate());
}
```

second

```
int serialDate()
{
    return m_date.serialNumber(); 
}

friend bool operator == (Date& a, Date& b)
{
    return (a.serialDate() == b.serialDate());
}
```

Comment: It isn't required by the language, but it is required by convention. Why would you forbid comparing with `const` instances?

Comment: my question is more why would you forbid comparing with non-const references? IOW why does the second code extract fail to compile?

Comment: @Marco My question is why would you not want to mark the parameters const?  The concept here is that you are telling the world that when doing a **comparison** you promise not to change the values you are comparing.

Comment: @Marco It is hard to say why it fails to compile without more information. Based on the code and error message, it sounds like you are trying to compare a `const` instance using your `operator==(Date&, Date&);`.

Comment: @Marco Note: none const values will bind to const parameters just fine.

Comment: @Marco I think Martin may have identified your misunderstanding. If you have `operator==(const T& const T&)` you can compare any combination of `const` and non-`const` instances together. With `operator==(T&, T&)` you can only compare a non-`const` instance with another non-`const` instance.

Comment: It seems that the problem is from the member function serialDate(), where it may access some const members.

Comment: The second code snippet did not fail for me when I added in the missing pieces to make it work.  I suspect the missing pieces from your code are incorrect for that use case.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux - I completely agree that you would want to make the parameters const, but since it was not a requirement - as you say - I was expecting the code to compile anyway.

Comment: @ytlu - thank you - I agree with your logic but serialDate() is not accessing const members as far as I can see. However, I will look further into this

Comment: @Eljay - would you be able to share the missing pieces to make it work? Thanks.

Comment: @Marco The missing piece referred by Eljay is just the code they guessed you might be using to run the code you shared. They tried to reproduce you problem by guessing what you might be doing with it, and they were not able to reproduce the problem. The missing piece you are asking about is in fact yours to share with us. It is not the secret to making your code work. Please read [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

As requested, here is my code of the second code snippet that passes in Date objects by (non-const) reference to the comparison routine.

The code has my additions to fill in for the missing pieces.  The code compiles, runs, and produces the expected output.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;

namespace {

struct SerialNumber {
    int d;
    int serialNumber() { return d; }
};

struct Date {
    SerialNumber m_date;

    int serialDate() {
        return m_date.serialNumber();
    }

    friend bool operator==(Date& a, Date& b) {
        return a.serialDate() == b.serialDate();
    }
};

} // anon

int main() {
    auto d1 = Date{{5}};
    auto d2 = Date{{5}};

    if (d1 == d2) {
        cout << "These are the same date.\n";
    } else {
        cout << "These are different dates.\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The code I'm using is very similar to this. I will take a deeper look into the Date member class.